# Handle click on disabled element (Pure JS)

Tags: javascript, dom

Has anybody ever had problem with handling click event on disabled input node? (Such problem appears in Firefox)

In Chrome and Safari it was solved by `div` wrapper,
but it doesn't work for Firefox.

CODE EXAMPLE NOT CURRENTLY SHOWING THE ISSUE:

```js
document.querySelector("#a").onclick=function() {
  console.log(this.disabled)
}
document.querySelector("#b").onclick=function() {
  console.log(document.querySelector("#c").disabled)
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" id="a" disabled /> Click </label>
<div id="b">
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="c" disabled /> Click</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Share your code

Comment: `had problem with handling click event on disabled input node` Sorry but what problem ?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: I created a snippet for you. Please update to show what exactly you mean

Comment: @mplungjan your snippet works fine in firefox, i dont think its a good idea to add code for OP, if he has a specific problem he should add his own problematic code part

Comment: @Banana - I had hoped Vadym would return and change the code to his specific issue or close it if the code worked. I was intrigued.